# How to get average date difference in PostgreSQL using EF Core 3

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq, entity-framework-core, npgsql

Using npgsql, EF Core 3 and a PostgreSQL database, I am trying to write the following SQL query in LINQ.

SQL:

```
SELECT date("EndDate"), avg("EndDate"-"StartDate") as avg_time
FROM trip
group by date("EndDate")
```

LINQ:

```
var q = from trip in _context.Trips
        group trip by trip.EndDate.Date into tripGroup
        select new { date = tripGroup.Key, avg_time_mins = tripGroup.Average(tg => (tg.EndDate - tg.StartDate).TotalMinutes) };
```

I tried with `TotalMinutes`, because `.Average( )` does not seem to take a TimeSpan. All efforts ended up with a runtime exception stating that this construct is not supported and suggesting to rewrite the query.

Answer (score 1):

If u want to TimeSpan as average using Linq(that what I understand from question)
first u have to understand average will be done in memory.

```
var groups = await _context.Trips.GroupBy(trip =>trip.EndDate.Date).ToArrayAsync() // load Them in memory

var q = groups.Select(group=> {
    var timeSpans = group.Select(trip=>trip.EndDate - trip.StartDate);
    var avg = GetAverage(timeSpans)
    return new {group.key, avg }
}).ToArray()


TimeSpan GetAverage(IEnumerable<TimeSpan> timeSpans){
 var average= timeSpans.Average(x => x.TotalMilliseconds)
 return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(average);
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a bad idea? The number of trips in my query is 10.000.000

Comment: yep. not always if its small 
thing is eventually u are loading every thing in memory.
no filtering after groupby, or on average.
and no pagination. 
what is ur actual usecase ?

Comment: computing the average time difference for each day in a month....around 300.000 records a day....the resulting 28-31 rows need to be delivered to the customer

Comment: 1- this query run how many times a day, month, a minute ?
2- I think u can break down ur query to each day. but 300,000 records still a big number.

Comment: Yes u can do it with chunks for each day.
1- first get only 10,000 record (or whatever number u like depends upon ur machine) for a particular date.
2-then get their time span in totalSecods in a list (why not time span directly? bcs long take less memory than timeSpan)
4- get next 10,000 records and repeat step 2
5-compute average through totalSecodsList

Comment: Hmmm. It seems easier just to create a stored procedure and call it. I was just hoping that I could do it directly in LINQ.

Comment: Yep.. because of size of ur data u are right 
Please don't forget to vote my any answer !!